# How move rectTransform of minimap when scale (Unity3d)

Tags: user-interface, unity-game-engine

I scale minimap and need shift minimap when size changed. My minimap align top left http://prntscr.com/ajroyg. I change size of rect minimap and try shift rect:

```
var value = sliderSize.value;
rect.localPosition = new Vector3(80f + value, -80f - value, 0);
rect.sizeDelta = new Vector2(157 * (value + 1), 157 * (value + 1));
```

But its shift very bad.

Comment: What does `shifting very bad` mean? Also, I think, if you could set the pivot to the top left corner without messing other stuff up, just scaling should do exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should just set the Anchor to (0,1) and Position to (0,0,0) which means that when you scale your map down you won't have to shift it.

That way, it will always stay in the top left corner.